# Which handle to pass to CreateIoCompletionPort, if using IOCP for basic signaling?

Tags: c, windows, signals, fifo, iocp

**Background**: As described in this article, [Designing Applications for High Performance](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/winserverperformance/2008/05/20/designing-applications-for-high-performance-part-ii/):

> Consider using `PostQueueCompletionStatus` rather than `SetEvent` API.  The latter boosts the target thread’s priority by 1 which may cause it to preempt something else.

I am working in C on Windows, and I'd like to replace signalling in a producer/consumer fifo from `SetEvent`/`WaitForSingleObject` to IO Completion Ports.

The reason is that I want the producer thread to be a background/low priority thread, but `SetEvent` always boosts the consumer thread and very often suspends my producer thread, which I would like to avoid to meet certain latency requirements.

Instrumentation for these methods show that I get delays in the order of ~50 microseconds in the producer thread every now and then, right after notifying the consumer thread using `SetEvent`, so if this is a cheap replacement I thought I might give it a try.

**Short version**: I want to switch something like this

```
void Produce(int some_item)
{
    Enqueue(some_item);
    SetEvent(hndEvent);
}

void Consume(void)
{
    while (true) 
    {
        if (WaitForSingleObject(hndEvent, INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            // consume
        }
    }
}
```

into something like this I guess:

```
void Produce(int some_item)
{
    Enqueue(some_item);

    unsigned long evt = 1; // "item enqueued"
    PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hndIOCP, 0, evt, NULL);
}

void Consume(void)
{
    while (true) 
    {
        unsigned long evt;
        LPOVERLAPPED ovlp;
        if (!GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hndIOCP, NULL, &evt, &ovlp, INFINITE))
            break;

        // consume
    }
}
```

But since I am not using this IOCP for anything other than signaling, what handle should I pass to `CreateIoCompletionPort`?

I thought I would simply do something like:

```
// single thread IOCP
hndIOCP = CreateIoCompletionPort(NULL, NULL, 0, 1);
```

but it just returns NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I missed the following part in the documentation for [`CreateIoCompletionPort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/createiocompletionport).

The first parameter is `FileHandle`, and if not used it has to be set to `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` instead of zero.

> **`FileHandle [in]`**
>
> An open file handle or **`INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`**.
>
> - The handle must be to an object that supports overlapped I/O.
> - If a handle is provided, it has to have been opened for overlapped I/O completion. For example, you must specify the **`FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`** flag when using the **`CreateFile`** function to obtain the handle.
> - If **`INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`** is specified, the function creates an I/O completion port without associating it with a file handle. In this case, the **`ExistingCompletionPort`** parameter must be `NULL` and the **`CompletionKey`** parameter is ignored.